# R-Commander, Rcmdr package - Can't load Data from existing environemnt + getting Q dialog boxes that won't close

Tags: r, r-commander

I am relatively new to the data world and R, I had been trying to use Rcpdr package - Commander. I have some basic questions.

I am using R 4.3.1, and I am running Windows 11. I recently installed the Rcmdr package to try out commander GUI tool for various taks. However, I am facing issues, please see the details as below:

1. Commander is not able to see the files in my current session of R-Studio. I can load data. However, I don't want to do that.
2. It keeps popping up Question dialog boxes when I am trying to navigate the tool. I cannot read anything. However, there is no way I can close those pop-up dialog boxes and they just keep growing.
3. How do you kill the Commander session? As this guy is stubborn and doesn't go away by File -> Exit -> both from R+Commander, Only Commander...

I thought it will be helpful and speedup things, its turning out to be the contrarily. Any pointers are appreciated!!

Regards
Kabir

Has anyone seen or experienced similar behaviour or Rcmdr - Commander? If Yes, how did you resolve it.

Any other tips or tricks.